# Deleting a site having subsites?

Tags: site-collection

How to delete a website which is having subsites in sharepoint 2010?
I dont like to go to down level and start up deleting?
i would like to delele site and subsites at a time?

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN Blog: Using PowerShell to Delete a Site with Subsites in SharePoint Server 2010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jjameson/using-powershell-to-delete-a-site-with-subsites-in-sharepoint-server-2010)

or

[SharePoint Automation: A Better Delete Web (stsadm extension)](https://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/a-better-delete-web/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Publishing Infrastructure enabled?  If so I believe you can do this from the Site Actions/Manage Content and Structure option.  Just chose delete from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to remove the site and it's corresponding sub-sites, whether by Powershell or programatically.

If you are wanting to do this programatically, according to [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607948%28v=office.14%29.aspx), you should be able to just use:

```
Remove-SPSite -Identity "http://sitename" -GradualDelete -Confirm:$False
```

Otherwise, the other code related snippet and link provided by @Stuart should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this via the Object Model, then you're going to have to recurse down through the sites and delete from the bottom up.

I've put together a function to do this (see below). However, I've also put together a more integrated solution in the form of an extension method, which can be found on my blog. [SPFix: Deleting a site with subsites programmatically](http://tsstsst.com/spfix-deleting-a-site-with-subsites-programmatically/)

```
public static void DeleteWeb(SPWeb web)
{
    foreach (SPWeb subWeb in web.Webs)
    {
        DeleteWeb(subWeb);
    }

    web.Delete();
}
```